# How to select text between ::before and ::after

Tags: html, css

How do I make a CSS selector to target the text in this example and not the whole h1 element? Just the text and not the before and after elements.

The before and after elements has a border-top, trying to add some animation to the text and not effect the border-top part.

```css
h1::before {border-top:1px solid #000;}

h1::after {border-top:1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<h1>my heading</h1>
```

edit: Thanks for the answers/comments guys, seems like this still isn't possible through css.

Comment: Pseudo-elements are not actually in the DOM, and therefore they can't be used in combination selectors to do what you're after. Maybe ask about your overall challenge instead of this very focused problem.

Comment: To put it another way, there _is_ no text between such pseudo-elements. Text in the parent element has no relationship to them.

Comment: How about fixing the snippet demo above up so we can see the actual scenario instead of a wonky mockup? Note that your h1 element was previously closed with an h2 tag.

Comment: `::before`  and `::after` pseudo elements are part of their elements and are virtually inserted as inline (text or image). If the element where they are virtually created and inserted is styled, it will not respond individually to those style set, even some  to some of inheritable rules( => inline content)They are part of the content. To avoid this, you have most of the time to reset their display behavior to anything else than inline and rewrite rules to overxwrite rules set on their element. position, float can also be used to overcome some rules, it has limits to what you can do, what it is

Comment: However they are not real elements and never external from the element that generated them, they don't really exist and cannot be selected. just pseudo elements. Aside `::after,::before` , there is more pseudo elements => see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
h1 :not(h1::before, h1::after){
//CSS here
}
```

It selects every h1 tag except the before and after.

Comment: If there's not a child element within the h1, this won't select anything

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

I think it looks like this in CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after {

}
```

Comment: CSS doesn't provide the means to select text. This particular code just selects every element and pseudo-element on the page, which is rarely useful.